# Loading local files in a WebBrowser Control

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-7, browser, local

Im trying to load local files in a WebBrowser on Windows Phone 7.1 but Im always getting exceptions or a blank page.

I tried with

```
Stream stream = Application.GetResourceStream(
                   new Uri("./Html/par/index.html", 
                   UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    // Navigate to HTML document string
    this.webBrowser.NavigateToString(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

this is firing a blank page.

I set index.html and all files needed (css/js) as Content and IsScriptEnable to "true".

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the path is incorrect.

do you have `/Html/par` directories in your project ? secondly is index.html set to content ?

try

```
var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("myFile.html", UriKind.Relative));
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.Stream))
{
    this.webBrowser.NavigateToString(sr.ReadToEnd()); 
}
```

this might help 
http://phone7.wordpress.com/2010/08/08/loading-a-local-html-file-in-the-webbrowser-control/

this might help undertand differences between resource and content
http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2011/09/30/images-and-build-actio-settings-in-wp7/

this link details how to load the file and other linked files 
http://transoceanic.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/wp7-load-local-html-files-and-all.html

Comment: StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(TitleContainer.OpenStream("test.html"));
webBrowser1.NavigateToString(reader.ReadToEnd());

I used this one as well. The problem is not the path but, actually, its loading the html specified but not the local scripts/style files/images.

Any idea how to stream those files too?

Comment: try this link http://transoceanic.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/wp7-load-local-html-files-and-all.html

Comment: thanks!!it's working like a charm but it's a shame we have to do this to load local files...I hope there is a second way...but this is the best answer!! cheers!

Comment: i'd agree... the easliest way is to have simplier html files with all css and javascript and not linking it. glad it worked

Comment: yes, I used this solution as well where I could use it...for images and long js im using the "copy" solution !! Thank you indeed!